# How to achieve serialization in Objective-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, serialization

I want to save an objects state permanently (as in serialization) and retrieve it according to the user need in an objective c project. In simple words, I want to serialize/deserialize an object. 
Please tell me the best way to achieve this in objective c iPhone project. I will be really thankful to you if u provide me a sample code or any tutorial.

Comment: Do some search on SO before posting Check the links  ..... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637787/archive-serialize-objective-c-object-with-c-instance-variables   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182115/make-a-custom-class-serializable-in-objective-c-iphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pList for serilization in objective C.

go through this link:- [Archives and Serializations Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html)

Comment: An archive is not a property list.

Answer (score 1):

You could save the objects in core data.

[Here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-getting-started) you have an tutorial.

And [Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) from Apple dev.

If you have less complicated object and relation you could save them as [NSSDictionaryes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) in [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html). [Here](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/10/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-savingretrieving-data-using-nsuserdefaults/) is an small tutorial.